# Resize iframe height dynamically dependent on the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I've seen the several other threads about this problem but I just cant find a solution for my problem.

My Code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('iframe').each(function() {
        $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("html").height() );
    });
});
```

Explanation: On window load, I am looping through every iframe on the page and put the height dependent on the content.

This works on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkSSH/512/) perfectly, but not on my webpage. Might there be anything ive missed?

It is **not** cross-domain. Iframe parent and Iframe are **definetly** on the same domain.

I have one idea:

I use an add-this facebook icon which is included via iframe. I get an error in firebug about "Permission denied..."(Cross-domain). Might this stop the other iframes from resizing?

Greetings.

Comment: `$(window).load(function() {` should be `$(function() {` or `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel wrong, you have to use `$(window).load(function () { });` because otherwise, your executing your script too early. The Images and Iframes are not ready when you execute the code that early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay my idea was right, the "Permission denied..." (Cross-domain) stopped the other code from working, its like a PHP Fatal Error. So I just used `find()` method to only get the iframes i want and resize it.

Works very well!

My Code

```
$(window).load(function() {
        $(".tx-smileiframe-pi1").find("iframe").each(function() {
            $(this).height( $(this).contents().find(".iframe").height() );
        });
    });
```